# SQL Query Behaviour

Tags: sql-server

I have a column called 'CLIENTDATA' in table CLIENTDET and have a data like 'last-ST - Tranactions - Challan Details - Int. Calc. - Interest Report -  N'.

**Case 1:**

When i write a query

```
SELECT CLIENTDATA,
       LEN(CLIENTDATA)
FROM   CLIENTDET
```

In this case i am getting correct data and length as '75'.

**Case 2:**

When i write a query

```
SELECT CAST(
           CASE 
                WHEN CLIENTDATA IS NULL THEN ''
                ELSE CLIENTDATA
           END AS 
           VARCHAR
       ),
       LEN(
           CAST(
               CASE 
                    WHEN CLIENTDATA IS NULL THEN ''
                    ELSE CLIENTDATA
               END 
               AS VARCHAR
           )
       )
FROM CLIENTDET

In this case i am not getting correct data as in Case 1, here length is '30'.
```

Anything i am missing here or not understood?.... Image is attached

[image]

Comment: I think it woud be cleaner if you use SELECT ISNULL(CLIENTLNAME,''), LEN(ISNULL(CLIENTLNAME,''))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you cast a literal to character type without specifying the length,
by default it is 30. 
So you need to specify the enough column length when you use character datatypes.
[Ref.](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/madhivanan/archive/2007/12/04/column-length-and-data-length.aspx)
and here [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

e.g.

```
Declare @a varchar(100)
Select @a='123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'

Select LEN(CAST(@a as Varchar)),LEN(@a)
```

as additonal information

When declaring a VARCHAR variable without defining the length, it will default to 1.

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR
SET @a = 'ABCDE'
SELECT @a
```

Returns: "1"